# Are fscanf and fprintf buffered in C?

Tags: c, io, buffer, scanf, stdio

I wish to write an efficient C program, that makes a copy of a file. There doesn't seem to be a function (such as [rename](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Renaming-Files.html)) that performs this. I plan to use [fscanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) an [fprintf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html) in stdio.h, but their descriptions do not say how or if they are buffered. Are they buffered between different cache levels? (I assume disk to memory buffer is handled by the OS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a file with `fopen`, it will be fully buffered.

You can change the buffering before doing any other operations on the file, using `setvbuf` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)).

Using any normal I/O functions on a `FILE` object will take advantage of the buffering.

If you are just copying the data, you will be doing sequential reads and writes, and will not necessarily need buffering.  But doing that efficiently does require choosing an appropriate block size for I/O operations.  Traditionally, this is related to the size of a disk sector (4096 bytes) but that value isn't future-proof.  The default used by `fopen` is `BUFSIZ`.

As with any optimisation, construct actual tests to verify your performance gains (or losses).

In the end, for the fastest I/O you might have to use OS-specific APIs.  The C I/O functions just map to the general case of those APIs, but there may be special performance settings for an OS that you cannot control through the C library.  I certainly ran into this when writing a fast AVI writer for Windows.  Using platform-specific I/O I was able to achieve the maximum read/write speed of the disk: twice the speed of buffered I/O (`<stdio.h>`) or the native AVI API, and about 20% faster than traditional C unbuffered I/O.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` and `scanf` family of functions are all part of the same buffered "interface". `man 3 stdio`:

> The  standard  I/O  library  provides a simple and efficient buffered
>   stream I/O interface.  Input and output is mapped into logical data
>   streams and the physical I/O characteristics are concealed.  The
>   functions and macros are  listed  below;  more information is
>   available from the individual man pages.

If you want to avoid buffering, you will have to use a different C library.